# Isometries of the Round Sphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Consider $(S^{n},g_{round})$ be the standard unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $g_{round}$ be the metric on $S^{n}$ induced by the standard metric from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The task is to show that the isometry group of $(S^{n},g_{round})$ consists of $O|_{S^{n}}$, where $O\in \mathcal{O}(n)$ (orthogonal group).

**So far I have the following:** Let $f : S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ be an isometry (meaning $f^{*}g_{round} = g_{round}$). Extend this to a contunous map $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by setting $\tilde{f}(x) = ||x||f(x/||x||)$ and $\tilde{f}(0)=0$. Now I am trying to show that $\tilde{f}$ preserves distances. By that I mean that $||\tilde{f}(x) - \tilde{f}(y)|| = ||x-y||$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. If I can show this then I can deduce that $\tilde{f}(x)=Ox$ for some $O \in \mathcal{O}(n)$.

**Question:** How do I show that $\tilde{f}$ preserves distances? For a hint I would be very thankful.

Greetings,
Phil

Comment: It’s easier to do with $f$ (because basically your statement is equivalent to $\tilde{f}$ being differentiable at $0$). First step, show $f$ is onto (eg its image is open). Second step, show that $f$ preserves lengths of path, and thus is $1$-Lipschitz for the geodesic distance. Third, show that you can assume that $f$ has two antipodal fixed points. Show that then the corresponding Equator is stable under $f$. Fourth, show that if the Equator is also made of fixed points, then $f$ must be the identity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I do not want to use too hard machenery like geodesic distance.

Comment: Is there any more "elementary" proof?

Comment: You don’t need the full machinery. You just need the fact that two points are not antipodal iff there is a path joining them with length $<\pi$.

Comment: But I would like to use the function $\tilde{f}$? Is there any elementary way?

Comment: @Mindlack: very interesting comments. Could you elaborate on the fact that differentiability of $\tilde f$ implies that $f$ is an isometry?

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: Obviously the only issue with differentiability is at $0$. But, for every unit vector $u$, and $r >0$, $\frac{\tilde{f}(0+tu)-\tilde{f}(0)}{t}$ goes as $t \rightarrow 0^+$ to $rf(u)$. So if $\tilde{f}$ is differentiable at $0$, $ru \longmapsto rf(u)$ is its derivative at $0$ and is, by definition, linear. It follows $f$ restriction of a linear function that maps $S^n$ into $S^n$, so $f$ orthogonal.

Comment: @Mindlack: what is $r$ ? But if you tend $t$ to $0$ from the negative side, then you might get a different limit.

Comment: I think you get $-rf(-u)$.

Comment: Then you still need to show that $f(-u)=-f(u)$.

Comment: @Philip: I miswrote, it’s $tru$ in the limit instead of $tu$. But yes, you get a different limit on the other side. They must be equal if $\tilde{f}$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: I guess that this is the point in showing that $\tilde{f}$ is differentiable at $0$. Because then its a $C^{1}-$diffeomorphism.